# Expo - Weird vertical FlatList behaviour on some Android devices

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using a FlatList package in my Expo app to display cards in a vertical manner.

On iOS it works perfectly but on Android and only one some devices (in works perfectly on Huaweis, Xiaomis, and the Pixel AVD) such as Samsungs, and no matter on which OS ; there is a vertical offset that is added on each swipe down; and the offset is getting larger and larger as we swipe;

The only lead I have is that on every swipe when I look up in the Expo Inspector, an offset is added in the parenthesis above the padding view like this (0.0, -34.0) for instance;
Apart from that the amazing Expo package made the development a swell and I would love to deploy on Android but this bug is too complicated to debug...

Comment: Hi there, consider adding a minimum reproducible demo using https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: Hi ! I would love to but it is straight up an already developed app with lots of logic already, it would take up too much time just to recreate an working snack

Comment: You could try to replicate just the flatlist part with dummy data.

Comment: This is exactly the issue https://snack.expo.io/@rezold/animated-listview-offbypixels-for-android

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code.

This line seems to be the culprit.

`getItemLayout={(_, index) => ({ length: itemSize, offset: itemSize * index, index })}`

Removing it seems to have smoothened the scroll.
Any reason why you need this part ?

Comment: This is not a smoothness issue this is a offset issue added on top of the div on every scroll.. Thanks for the idea, it didn't fix in the snack tho